# Extract emacs c style options from clang-format style

Tags: c++, emacs, formatting, clang, clang-format

A colleague provided me with a clang-format style file for a C++ project we are working on. I installed [clang-format.el](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/tools/clang-format/clang-format.el) in order to be able to format a buffer from emacs. Reformatting works as expected. Emacs default c-mode indentation is still completely different, though.

I find it quite disturbing to destroy the source code formatting when editing and restore it later. Is there any way to read a clang-format file and apply the corresponding cc-mode options?

Answer (score 9):

I am not aware if there is any direct conversion tool. However, you can try to use following trick:

1. Concatenate decent amount of C++ files from your project into single one (for instance `cat *.cpp > single.cpp`)
2. Apply clang-format to that `single.cpp`
3. Open `single.cpp` within Emacs
4. Use [guess](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Guessing-the-Style.html) feature of CC-mode: `M-x c-guess-no-install` and then `M-x c-guess-view`

Comment: This is a brilliant answer!
`c-guess-no-install` reads only the first `c-guess-region-max` bytes which for me defaulted to 50k which I vastly exceeded. `c-guess-buffer-no-install` did the trick for my code.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit late on this, but hopefully someone will still find this useful. I've posted the relevant portion of my clang-format config below, which provides the functionality you want.

```lisp
(use-package clang-format
  :after (s)
  :init
  (defun get-clang-format-option (config-str field is-num)
    "Retrieve a config option from a clang-format config.

CONFIG-STR is a string containing the entire clang-format config.
FIELD is specific option, e.g. `IndentWidth'.  IS-NUM is a
boolean that should be set to 1 if the option is numeric,
otherwise assumed alphabetic."
    (if is-num
        (let ((primary-match (s-match (concat "^" field ":[ \t]*[0-9]+") config-str)))
          (if primary-match
              (string-to-number (car (s-match "[0-9]+" (car primary-match))))
            0))
      (let ((primary-match (s-match (concat "^" field ":[ \t]*[A-Za-z]+") config-str)))
        (if primary-match
            (car (s-match "[A-Za-z]+$" (car primary-match)))
          ""))))
  :hook (c-mode-common . (lambda ()
                           (let* ((clang-format-config
                                   (shell-command-to-string "clang-format -dump-config"))
                                  (c-offset (get-clang-format-option clang-format-config "IndentWidth" t))
                                  (tabs-str (get-clang-format-option clang-format-config "UseTab" nil))
                                  (base-style
                                   (get-clang-format-option clang-format-config "BasedOnStyle" nil)))
                             (progn
                               (if (> c-offset 0)
                                   (setq-local c-basic-offset c-offset)
                                 (if (not (equal "" base-style))
                                     (cond ((or (equal "LLVM" base-style)
                                                (equal "Google" base-style)
                                                (equal "Chromium" base-style)
                                                (equal "Mozilla" base-style))
                                            (setq-local c-basic-offset 2))
                                           ((equal "WebKit" base-style)
                                            (setq-local c-basic-offset 4)))))
                               (if (not (equal "" tabs-str))
                                   (if (not (string-equal "Never" tabs-str))
                                       (setq-local indent-tabs-mode t)
                                     (setq-local indent-tabs-mode nil))
                                 (if (not (equal "" base-style))
                                     (cond ((or (equal "LLVM" base-style)
                                                (equal "Google" base-style)
                                                (equal "Chromium" base-style)
                                                (equal "Mozilla" base-style)
                                                (equal "WebKit" base-style))
                                            (setq-local indent-tabs-mode nil))))))))))
```

I use [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package). If you don't, you will have to make some minor adjustments. Additionally, note that I use [s.el](https://github.com/magnars/s.el) for string manipulation.

The code looks for "IndentWidth" and "UseTab". If it finds "UseTab" and it isn't set to "Never", I set `indent-tabs-mode` to `t`. Otherwise I set it to `nil`. The value for "IndentWidth" goes to `c-basic-offset`. If these fields are not found, but "BasedOnStyle" is found, the appropriate values are set based on that style. I have not included the Microsoft style since my version of clang-format won't give me a config dump for it (presumably it's in a later version). "IndentWidth" and "UseTab" override the behavior of "BasedOnStyle" which accords with clang-format's behavior. Finally, note that `c-basic-offset` and `indent-tabs-mode` are set as buffer local variables so this setup works as expected when working on several files with different configs.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work. I added it to the user-config section of my .spacemacs.